# Sequalize association cannot see models

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Hello I have problem with visibility of models in associaton "field". There is code which will show the problem:
When I do something like this:

**Applications.js**

```
'use strict';    
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Applications = sequelize.define('Applications', {
    id: { type:DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true},
    team_id:DataTypes.INTEGER,
    paid:DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
      freezeTableName: true,
      tableName: 'applications',
      timestamps:false,
      classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
          Applications.belongsTo(models.Teams, {foreignKey:'team_id', as: 'team'});
      }
    }
  });

  Applications.sync({force: false});
  return Applications;
};
```

**Teams.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Teams = sequelize.define('Teams', {
    id: { type:DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    phone: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName:'teams',
    timestamps:false,
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
          Teams.hasOne(models.Applications, {foreignKey:'team_id', as: 'team'});
      }
    }
  });

  Teams.sync({force: false});
  return Teams;
};
```

**Router.js**

```
router.get('/applications', function(req, res, next) {
    models.Applications.findAll({where:{id: 7},include:['team']}).then(function (value) { res.send(value) });   
});
```

Then I get error which saying that there is no association between these two models. But when I add associations to Router everything start working.
Code which is working:

```
models.Teams.hasOne(models.Applications, {foreignKey:'team_id', as: 'team'});
models.Applications.belongsTo(models.Teams, {foreignKey:'team_id', as: 'team'});

router.get('/applications', function(req, res, next) {
    models.Applications.findAll({where:{id: 7},include:['team']}).then(function (value) { res.send(value); });
});
```

Comment: So what is the problem ?

Comment: These associations should be in associate: function(models) { }, like in many examples in documentations. I don t know why It doesn't work when I do as it should be. I agree it works but in docs they show other way xD

Answer (score 0):

The associate function of classMethods should be called to create the association.

See below code for reference -

```
Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
   if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
       db[modelName].associate(db);
   }
});
// Here all associate function are called one by one.
```

You have defined the associate function but it is not being executed before sync.

Normally, we make an index.js file to associate all association and in that file, you call associate function of each model.

Comment: I removed sync, I added things to association method and still doesn't work I have got : ' Unhandled rejection Error: Association with alias "team" does not exists', I also change code in index.js  to your. I started debugging with console.log and it seems that associate fields still have never been called.  Also code in Object.keys(db)...[...] too.